Unable to Find "App Password" Option in Microsoft 365 Email Through GoDaddy
I am managing a Microsoft 365 email account through GoDaddy for my company, and I'm trying to set up App Passwords for use with our email verification system. However, when I go to the Security Info section and select Add Sign-in Method, the App Password option does not appear in the drop-down.
Here’s what I’ve already tried:

MFA (Multi-Factor Authentication) is enabled for the account.
I've checked and disabled Security Defaults as suggested in some articles.
I've ensured Legacy Authentication is not blocked in Azure AD.

Despite these steps, I still can't see the option to add an App Password. Has anyone else encountered this issue with GoDaddy and Microsoft 365? Any ideas on how to get the App Password option to appear or potential workarounds?
Thank you in advance for your help!


If MFA is enabled on the account then you should be selecting Authenticator App, Go Daddy offering, isn’t Enterprise (Corporate) so it won’t support the options on the right side of that screenshot

Agree with Ramhound, it does not support this option.
